# Template class as a function parameter [C++]

Tags: c++, templates

The premise of the question is how to pass a templated class as a parameter to another function or at least get the same effect:

Below is a stripped-down version of my code

```
template<uint8_t _bus>
class Com {
public:
    uint8_t write() { return _bus; /* does something with template param */}
};


class Instruction
{
public:
    int member;
    void transmitFrame(char *msg) { 
        member = Com.write(msg); /* need to pass in Com object somehow */
    }
};

main(){
    Com<8> myCom;
    Instruction myInstruction;

    char[] msg = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    myInstruction.transmitFrame(msg);
}
```

The code above will not compile.
My first thought would be to just extend the `Com` class however as far as I am aware you can not extend class templates. My second thought would be to have a template inside a template? (so make the `Instruction` class a template class with a template of the `Com` template) But I am in the weeds on that one and not sure if that is possible.

The `Com` object has been instantiated by the time I am trying to use the `Instruction` class. So somehow, I need to get the templated `Com` object into the `Instruction` class so that I can access it.

At that point I am out of ideas...

Comment: Missing the final `}` and `;` after the template class definition. Attempt to return an integral from void-function. You can't call `main()`, it looks so at least w/o a returning `int`. `char[] msg` - are you sure it's C++?

Comment: `template<uint8_t N> void transmitFrame(Com<N>& com, char *msg) { com.write(msg); }`?

Comment: @273K Yah sorry the code got a little messy when I stripped it down, I made the edits. Definitely sure it's c++ ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to call `write` on the `Com` class directly, rather than an instance.

You likely want to pass an instance of `Com` to `transmitFrame`, but to do that you have to pass the template info.

```
template <uint8_t N>
void transmitFrame(Com<N> &com, char *msg) { 
    com.write(msg); /* need to pass in Com object somehow */
}
```

Or if you know the template value will be `8`.

```
void transmitFrame(Com<8> &com, char *msg) { 
    com.write(msg); /* need to pass in Com object somehow */
}
```